# Transformar Objeto en array map - rxjs - Angular - Error

Tags: angular, rxjs

Estimados estoy iterando un objeto en el cual quiero transformar u obtener solo los elementos del array con map pero la llave del objeto cuando intento acceder me da error. voy a dejar codigo y capturas para un mejor entendimiento. Intenete con pluck y si me transforma pero me indica el compilador que pluck esta en desuso, que utilice map, pero obtengo ese error.
Gracias.

```js
// Servicio

import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Incident } from "../interfaces/incidencia.interface";
import { environments } from "src/environments/environments";


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ServiceIncidencia {

    private baseUrl: string = environments.baseUrl;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

    getIncidencias(): Observable<Incident[]>{
        return this.http.get<Incident[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/incidents`)
    }
}



// interface

export interface Incidencia {
    incident: Incident[];
}

export interface Incident {
    _id:            string;
    nombre:         string;
    description:    string;
    user:           Typeofincident;
    typeofincident: Typeofincident;
    disponible:     boolean;
}

export interface Typeofincident {
    _id:    string;
    nombre: string;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
// componente

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Incident } from '../interfaces/incidencia.interface';
import { ServiceIncidencia } from '../services/incidencia.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-incidencias',
  templateUrl: './incidencias.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class IncidenciasComponent implements OnInit {
 
  incident: Incident[] = [];
 

  constructor( private serviceIncidencia: ServiceIncidencia){

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.serviceIncidencia.getIncidencias()
   .pipe(
    map(resp => resp.incident)
   )
   .subscribe(console.log)
    
}}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

respuesta que se obtiene sin acceder con la llave incident

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este error lanza cundo coloco la llave incident

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si utilizo pluck si transforma, pero como comente me indica que esta en desuso. y obtenego el array transformado o sin la llave incident solo el array.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: "me da error" -> Y qué error te da?? No somos adivinos. Usa el enalce [edit] para añadir el error EXACTO y de paso el modelo, porque lo primero que me viene a la cabeza es que tu objeto `Incident` no tiene un array `incidents` dentro, pero claro, me lo tengo que inventar porque no puedo verlo :)

Comment: Gracias por responder, la captura del pipe y map hay una llave quese llama incident,la marque con una flecha roja que esta claro en la imagen y el compilador indica esto (Property 'incident' does not exist on type 'Incident[])

Comment: hay una propiedad incident: Incident[] = []; en la parte superior que viene de una interface, nesecitas ver la interface?

Comment: El error te está diciendo exactamente lo que pasa... y si obviamente si te da un error el modelo (la interfaz en este caso) DEBES mostrarla. El problema es que el objeto que te está llegando y tu interfaz no son iguales, en tu interfaz no tienes la propiedad `incidents`. Cambia lo que devuelves en la API o actualiza tu modelo acorde.

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en tu función "getIncidencias", probablemente esta función esté definida algo así como:

`getIncidencias(): Incident[]`

esto le dice al intellisense que espera recibir un **array** cuando en verdad (por lo que muestras) estas recibiendo un **objeto** mas o menos del tipo:

```
{
    incident: Incident[]
}
```

puedes corregir la definición de tu función o bien saltar esta comprobación usando la notación con brackets

```
this.serviceIncidencia.getIncidencias()
.pipe(
    map(resp => resp['incident'])
)
.subscribe(console.log)
```

**EDIT**

acabo de ver bien y claro tienes definida la función qué dice retornar un array pero el API te entrega un objeto por lo que en verdad tu función debe decir que retorna el objecto `{ incident: Incident[] }` o bien hacer el map en el `ServiceIncidencia` que tiene mas sentido. La solución ideal sería

```
export class ServiceIncidencia {
....

this.http.get<Incident[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/incidents`)
.pipe(
    map(resp => resp['incident'])
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**solucion**
Servicio:

En el archivo de servicio se uso un pipe con el operador map para transformar el objeto en un array utilizando las llave ['incident'], ayudo a llegar a transformar, pero me lanzaba el error del tipo de datos, utilizando as keyof typeof resp, es donde le digo que el tipo de dato y a que valor le debe asignar a la resp, con esto ya me trae la infrmacion o la respuesta transformada.

```js
  getIncidencias():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<Incident[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/incidents`)
      .pipe(map(resp => resp['incident' as keyof typeof resp])
    );
  }
```

**Componente:**

en el componente invoco el servicio con la data ya transformada y me subscribo a mi instancia o interface y le indico que sea igual a la respuesta que se trae del servicio con los datos transformados, y utlizo esa llave para recorrer el arreglo en el html con *ngFor

```js
public incidents: Incident[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.serviceIncidencia
      .getIncidencias()
      .subscribe(
        (resp) => {(this.incidents = resp)}
      );
  }
```

```html
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" *ngFor="let item of incidents; let i = index">
  <li
    class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start"
    routerLink="/incidencias/resueltas"
  >
    <div class="arrow">
      <fa-icon [icon]="faChevronRight"></fa-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
      <div class="time">hace 40 min</div>
      <div class="fw-bold mb-3">{{item.nombre}} <span class="number">{{i+1}}</span></div>
      {{item.description}}
    </div>
        <div [ngSwitch]="item.typeofincident.nombre">
            <div *ngSwitchCase="'Duda'">
                <span class="badge bg-duda rounded-pill"
                    ><fa-icon [icon]="faGraduationCap"></fa-icon
                    ><span class="info">{{item.typeofincident.nombre}}</span>
                    </span>
            </div>
            <div *ngSwitchCase="'Integración'">
                <span class="badge bg-integracion rounded-pill"
                    ><fa-icon [icon]="faCannabis"></fa-icon
                    ><span class="info">{{item.typeofincident.nombre}}</span>
                    </span>
            </div>
            <div *ngSwitchCase="'Pedido'">
                <span class="badge bg-pedido rounded-pill"
                    ><fa-icon [icon]="faWandMagic"></fa-icon
                    ><span class="info">{{item.typeofincident.nombre}}</span>
                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Respuesta del JSON sin llaves:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).